# How to order by particular records from field in serialize format in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

I'm in big trouble in mysql/php.

I've stored `address/city/country` etc, in database using serialize method.
But now, I don't know how to find particular city from serialize data and how to sort this records in mysql.

My serialize data is :

```
a:6:{s:12:"country_code";s:2:"IT";s:10:"country_id";s:3:"105";s:7:"Address";s:16:"Via Emilia 234/B";s:3:"Zip";s:5:"40068";s:4:"City";s:21:"San Lazzaro Di Savena";s:8:"Province";s:2:"BO";}
```

I want to find *province = "BO"* from above data and also sort this data by province in asc or desc order.

I don't want to use like.

Please help me!

Comment: Well, if your data is in your MySQL table you can just run a query to retrieve them sorted... I don't understand what the issue here is...

Comment: i don't know how to retrieve match data. For example province='BO' and also  how to  sort the data by city
So,Its  issue

Comment: Please do us both a favor and read up before posting a question like this on SO. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: Also, read up on your SQL http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

Comment: I know how to fetch the records but I don't know how to fetch records while the data store using serialize method and how to find particular province from serialize data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you choosed to store php serialized value in a db column (schemaless paradigm?) which is not understod by mysql engine (that sees it as a text value), you locked out yourself to use sql based on that values (except string functions).

What you can do is for those fields you want `order by` `where` etc. create columns.

With postgresql you may choose `JSONB` to stay schemaless but use sql on value , i am not familiar with mysql's json support.